# How to run all input test files from a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

This may be a very noob question, but I have no idea of how to solve it. I have a C program and a folder called "input". Is it possible to write rules that allow me to type "make run" and then execute all test instances, writing the result into a single file?

I imagine that it's something like:

```
run: test1 test2 test3

test1:
    ./myproj < arq1.in > output.out

test2:
    ./myproj < arq2.in > output.out

...
```

But how do I achieve that everyone writes into the same file, ie, appending the results, instead of rewriting it? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First switch to ">>" to *append* to the output file:

```
run: test1 test2 test3

test1:
    ./myproj < arq1.in >> output.out

test2:
    ./myproj < arq2.in >> output.out

test3:
    ./myproj < arq3.in >> output.out
```

Then make those targets PHONY, because they are (i.e. they do not build files named "test1", "test2" and "test3"):

```
.PHONY: test1 test2 test3
```

Then switch to a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
run: test1 test2 test3

.PHONY: test1 test2 test3

test1 test2 test3: test%:
    ./myproj < arq$*.in >> output.out
```

Further refinements are possible, but that's enough for now.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Not at all, thank you for the correction.